# How can I set encoding for iText when I insert value to placeholder in pdf form?

Tags: java, pdf, encoding, itext, pdf-form

I tried fill pdf form. I have template and fill it my data.

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FontFactory.register(BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);
        PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest));
        AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
        String[] split = reportDTO.note.split("\\n");
        form.setField("field1", "Значение");//value is some text in UTF-8
```

but my value not insert to `field1` palceholder. it is empty. But if value in English for example

```
form.setField("field1", "some text");
```

this text insert sucsessuful.

How can I set encoding for insert text in normal view?

Comment: I think there is a problem with pdf-file fonts. Maybe you should add the right font by using method **addSubstitutionFont** on **form** variable: `form.addSubstitutionFont(/*Here is your font for utf-8 or Cp1251 encoding*/)`

Comment: What is the intent of `FontFactory.register(BaseFont.IDENTITY_H)`? The register method is documented to *register a ttf- or a ttc-file* but `BaseFont.IDENTITY_H` is an encoding name.

Answer (score 1):

One of the solutions:

1) Download font which contains all symbols in unicode (you use)

2) Create font with encoding (Cp1251, Cp1250, utf8 etc)

3) Than you should add the font by using AcroFields's addSubstitutionFont method on form variable.

```
    public static final String **FONT = "resources/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF";**

    somemethod(){
    **Font font = FontFactory.getFont(FONT, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);**
    BaseFont baseFont = font.getBaseFont();

    PdfStamper stamper = null;
    try {
         stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(fileDestination));
         AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();
         form.addSubstitutionFont(baseFont);
         form.setField("field1", "Значение");
    ... // other fields, catch etc
    }
```